# How do I express "more than all other X" in FOL?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I have a question I need to express in FOL, "Some pianist is more lazy than all other pianists." I've been racking my brain but I can't quite get it.

P(x)... x is a pianist
L(x,y)... x is more lazy than y

My best guess is AxEy(~x=y<->(P(y)&P(x)&L(y,x)))

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First off, this is clearly an existential sentence, so it should start with $\exists x$, not with $\forall x$

In fact, the sentence is saying about some pianist, so the basic form will be $$\exists x (P(x) \land \phi(x))$$

where $\phi(x)$ is what we want to express about this pianist $x$.

Now, what we want to say about this pianist $x$ is that $x$ is lazier than all other pianists. To do that, think about it this way: if you take any pianist $y$ other than $x$, it will be the case that $x$ is lazier than $y$. So, we can express $\phi(x)$ as:

$$\forall y ((P(y) \land y \neq x) \to L(x,y))$$

So, plug that into the basic form above, and the result is:

$$\exists x (P(x) \land \forall y ((P(y) \land y \neq x) \to L(x, y)))$$

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it!!